# Error when editing a datagridview with a connected MySQL database. An error appears when trying to save

Tags: c#, mysql, forms, datagridview

When trying to edit the datagridview, an error appears "The CommandText property has not been properly initialized.". I read that some other stored procedure is needed, which as input parameters it takes the first name, last name and patronymic and phone number of the user and returns his id, if so, how to implement it on mysql link to the source: https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.11.php , https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/3.5.php
Program code:

```
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SD = System.Data;

namespace DBredaction
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
            DataSet ds;
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
            MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder;
            string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=catalog;Uid=root;pwd=;charset=utf8;";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
            public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);

                ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                // делаем недоступным столбец id для изменения
                dataGridView1.Columns["Id"].ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        //public MySqlConnection mycon;
        //public MySqlCommand mycom;
        //public string connect = "Server=localhost;Database=catalog;Uid=root;pwd=;charset=utf8;";
        //public SD.DataSet ds;
        //public MySqlCommand mycon2;otchestvo

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try { 
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
                commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                adapter.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("", connection);
                adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@imia",    MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Имя"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@familia", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Фамилия"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@otchestvo", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Отчество"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@telephon", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 11, "Телефон"));
                

                MySqlParameter parameter = adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int16, 0, "Id");
                parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                adapter.Update(ds);
            }
        }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("DB CONNECT");
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection lost");
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow(); 
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I am not that familiar with MySQL and could be mistaken about this, however, it appears the error is suggesting that you have not specified “which” stored procedure you want to use with … `adapter.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("", connection);` … the first parameter is the sql statement or in this case the stored procedures name? I am confident you would somewhere have to specify “which” stored procedure to use and I do not see that anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: Also, the code in the button3 click event… will most likely throw an error. There will be a problem removing rows from the same collection the `foreach` loop is looping through. And if the grid uses a data source (as it appears to), then you will get an error that you cannot remove rows directly from the grid when it is a data bound grid.

Comment: And could you help in creating a stored procedure as input parameters, it should take the first name, last name, patronymic and phone number and return its id?

Comment: It's a shame that you're using MySQL; if it was another db I could have reduced this entire code to about 3 lines, all written by visual studio with abou 15 mouse clicks, but alas there's a long standing bug in some MySQL components that cripple the usefulness of the VS designer. That said, if your database doesn't calculate any values, or you're prepared to manually edit an xml file  then it shouldn't affect you.. Let me know

Comment: There are many examples of how to do this. What have you tried? You need to write the insert command in your code or the DB as a stored procedure. It may be easier if you drop the stored procedure aspect of this and simply write the sql in your code, however, using a stored procedure would be a better approach. I was under the impression the stored procedure had already been created.

Comment: @JohnG you don't need to write the insert command; that's what the command builder does, however it won't overwrite an InsertCommand set elsewhere, so providing a do-nothing command prevents it from working as intended. A person either uses a command builder or writes the insert/update/delete themselves, not usually both (unless eg they want to tweak the commands written)

Comment: I would like to write the insert database command in my code as a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work quite like that; if you're assigning a command builder to an adapter you don't then also set the XxxCommand DML properties yourself; the command builder does that from looking at the SelectCommand, working out the table schema and writing the queries.

I'd have the adapter at class level in a dedicated repository class, where the select, connstr and command builder are set:

```
//in the constructor of the repo class
_myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT here", "connstr here");
_commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(_myDataAdapter);
```

the fill code runs:

```
//in a GetData method of the repo class

DatTable dt = new DataTable();
_myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
return dt;
```

and the relevant I/U/D commands can be triggered:

```
//in a SaveChanges(DataTable) method of the repo class
_myDataAdapter.Update(dt);
```

See [https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommandBuilder.html](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql%7EDevart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommandBuilder.html) for more background info on the CB; their example code is based on a complete programmatic "fill, change, save" workflow so it's all in one method, but your workflow is essentially interrupted by the user needing to do the changes in the grid, hence breaking it up.

If you want to do it in one method, you can make your adapter, make your command builder and then set the I/U/D commands on the adapter by calling the relevant GetXxx on the command builder

Note that the command builder doesn't use stored procedures; that thing you've read about needing to make a stored procedure to update/insert data isn't the only way to save data to a db, and if you have created a sproc and are hoping to use it, forget a command builder; you'll have to do the command setup yourself